# Convert table to key value pair

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to flatten my current table. At the moment I was able to achieve this through an iterative approach but the run time is very poor. I queried the table and then used a cursor to iterate and insert into a new table.

My current table has many many columns and I'm trying to have it flattened. Possibly unpivot.

```
RecordId    FirstName    LastName    Country     Grade
-------------------------------------------------------
1           Joe          Fresh       Canada      95
2           John         Smith       Canada      94
```

The new table would look like this

```
RecordId    Key        Value
--------------------------------
1           FirstName   Joe
1           LastName    Fresh
1           Country     Canada
1           Grade       95
2           FirstName   John
2           LastName    Smith
2           Country     Canada
2           Grade       94
```

May I have some guidance.

I tried unpivot and was able to flatten the table but I'm missing `RecordId` column

```
select [Key], [Value]
from
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM test
) src
unpivot
(
  [Value] for [Key] in ([RecordId],[FirstName],[LastName], [Country], [Grade])
)
```

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to actually modify the schema. If so, this is a mistake. The desired result is called Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV), and it's a known **anti-pattern**... that is, something to avoid. However, it's fine if you just want to return the data this way for a query.

Comment: Despite the wise advice not to use this in production, especially if you are doing a PIVOT behind which is stupid... So at least do it with an "IN MEMORY" table!

Comment: @SQLpro please refrain from the negatively and stick to answering the posted question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is unpivoting. Please include the RecordId column in the unpivoted result by adding it to the SELECT statement before the UNPIVOT operation. Try this:

```
SELECT RecordId, [Key], [Value]
FROM
(
  SELECT RecordId, FirstName, LastName, Country, Grade
  FROM test
) src
UNPIVOT
(
  [Value] FOR [Key] IN (FirstName, LastName, Country, Grade)
) unpvt;
```

Answer (score 1):

I find using *cross apply* is usually easier and allows more flexability:

```
select t.RecordId, v.*
from t
cross apply(values
    ('FirstName', FirstName), 
    ('LastName', LastName), 
    ('Country', Country), 
    ('Grade', Cast(Grade as varchar(10)))
)v([key], [value]);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep that in min! Just at the moment I have 120+ columns, pivot was easier to write.

Comment: I think @Master if I had 120 columns to transpose I'd quickly select the column names from `sys.columns` and build either pivot or cross-apply query in seconds, sod all that typing lol